# Create delegate via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, delegates

Given an assembly that contains

```
namespace Foo{public class Bar;}
```

How could I create an `Action<Foo.Bar>` from another assembly without referencing the first assembly at compile time?

Comment: What do you mean by "without referencing the first assembly"? If you want to use a type from that assembly then you'll need to refer to it in some way.

Comment: Sorry, I mean without adding it as a reference to the Visual Studio project. i.e. use Assembly.LoadFrom() to load it so that there are no compile-time dependencies.

Comment: @LukeH - Edited question to be a bit clearer. Thanks for the input.

Comment: What would you do with the delegate if you can't assign it to a variable because you don't the type at compile-time? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dtb - In my scenario, I have a constructor in the source assembly that accepts `Action<Foo.Bar>`. So I wish to create an `Action<Foo.Bar>` to pass to said constructor via reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use

```
Type barType = Type.GetType("Foo.Bar, whateverassembly");
Type actionType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(barType);
```

`actionType` will now represent `Action<Foo.Bar>`. However, to use it, you'll need to contintue to use reflection, so you'll need to find a `MethodInfo` that fits the signature `void(Foo.Bar)`, and call `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create a delegate. And you'll need `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` to execute it.

```
Delegate call = Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, ...);
...
call.DynamicInvoke(someBar);
```

Something tells me that's not what you're thinking of...

Comment: What would I put in the  `...` in `Delegate.CreateDelegate(actionType, ...);`? I think your solution is what I require, because I will be passing this delegate to a constructor in the source assembly anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call it `Action<Foo.Bar>` in your calling code, since you won't have access to that type definition if you don't reference it at compile time. Since Delegates are contravariant, you can return an `Action<Object>` and use that, or use `Action<IBar>` where the `IBar` interface is defined in a referenced assembly, and implemented by `Foo.Bar`.

If you do return an `Action<Object>`, you'd either have to use `Foo.Bar` members via reflection (or `dynamic` if using C# 4.0) or use cast it to `Foo.Bar` where the casting code has a reference to the assembly where `Foo.Bar` is defined.

Comment: "You can't call it Action<Foo.Bar> in your calling code" - yeah I realize that. Re: contravariance - Sorry I didn't specify .NET 3.5. I'll fix the tags.