# select for dynamic result

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I couldn't make this work, I have dynamic result and I need to Select it to a new object.

```
var getMethod = SubType.BaseType.BaseType.GetMethod("List").MakeGenericMethod(SubType);

dynamic result = getMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { UId.ToGuid() });

return ((IEnumerable)result.Value).Select(c => new { c.UId, Text = GetPropertyValue(c, SubText) });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy. You will have to use `Reflection` for `Select` as well. You need to use `MakeGenericMethod` pass the `SubType` and get the correct overload of `Select`.

Then you need also create a `Func<>` delegate and then pass it to Select's `Invoke` method.I would suggest you create a named type instead of selecting anonymous type then creating a Func would be easier.You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024253/create-delegate-via-reflection) about how to create a Delegate type via `Reflection`.

Here is some sample code to start:

```
var select = typeof (Enumerable)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .First(m => m.Name == "Select" &&
                    m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);

var selectMethod = select.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SubType));

var func = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(SubType, ResultType);

...
```

Comment: my programming skills not enough for this I think :(

Answer (score -1):

try changing last line to :

```
return ((IEnumerable)result.Value).Select(c => new { UId = c.UId, Text = GetPropertyValue(c, SubText) });
```

All properties on a dynamic object need naming.